# Pullup bar attachment to make existing pullup bar lower

Tags: exercise, strength, exercise-equipment, calisthenics, equipment

Has anyone seen equipment, a pullup bar that attaches to an existing pullup bar to make it lower. Like a pullup bar with hooks that attachs so athlete can use a lower height version?

Note: Looking for static bar, not cable rings or hooks which I am familiar with

Comment: I have, but no idea where. Could get some of those single-hand climbing trainers (mine are Metolius) or similar and hang them from the bar, or a couple pieces of rope and a pipe (but make sure the pipe can't slip out!)

Comment: hi @DaveNewton do you have a google or amazon url link? so I can see what you are referring to, thanks !

Comment: Why do you want a pullup bar attachment to make it lower? Are you wanting to be able to change the bar height mid workout for some other exercises, or is this so someone who is a bit shorter? A bit of context might help us come up with some type of solution.

Comment: hi @EricWarburton I just wanted to leverage an existing bar, get an attachment bar which comes with two sturdy hooks, to attach make it lower, yeah, I wanted to incorporate other calisthenics exercises, thanks

Comment: I'm thinking Dave Newton's comment is likely the closest you are going to get to a 'static' bar hanging from another bar. I suspect you could build something with clamps or hooks at the top, but it likely isn't worth the effort over simply drilling some holes in each end of a bar, running some rope through and tying it to the other bar. As he mentions in his answer, be careful, what you are trying to do sounds a bit sketchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closest to what you're asking for are basically "bars with hooks".

[Here's a pair from FitBar](https://www.fitbarstrong.com/ocr-ninja-warrior-equipment/pull-up-handles):

[image: Image of small bars with hooks to hang from a pullup bar]

Depending on your needs/goals something like a [Metolius Rock Ring](https://www.metoliusclimbing.com/rock_rings.html) might end up being more versatile:

[image: Image of Metolius Rock Rings, climbing training equipment]

There are a lot of companies that make similar items; if these don't meet your needs, searching for "obstacle course racing training equipment" or "climbing training gear" or something should turn up more options.

---

There's a lot of options for the make-y inclined, some easier than others. The only caution is that over-engineering/-speccing here is recommended. Nothing with under ~500lb/220kg-ish specs. Use abrasion-resistant cord (like Spectra) or webbing.

I know more than one person (ok, two, but still) people that were *seriously* injured on make-shift equipment (one paralyzed). Just because we're talking about door-jamb-level heights doesn't mean Really Bad Things can't happen.

Disclaimer-y rant over, but srsly, be careful.

Comment: Looking for static bar, not cable rings or hooks which I am familiar with, thanks

Comment: @mattsmith5 There's no way to make it "static" unless you t-clamp it to the bar and/or have other attachment points available (and even a t-clamp isn't going to be as static as the bar unless you drill through the bar, and even *then*, it's likely to flex).

Answer (score 2):

Gymnastic rings.  They come with straps so you can adjust them to any height.  Insanely adaptable.

Comment: Looking for static bar, not cable rings or hooks which I am familiar with, thanks